# Creating Custom Layouts to Present Data

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find a package, or a solution that allows me to create custom layouts to present data. Similar to how one can create custom templates and layouts in Microsoft Word.

I've tried a `RichTextBox` but they are very limited. I want to create numerous custom layout types to present the data within my software and have the user select one they wish to use, with the option of printing.

Is there anything that will allow me to do this?

This is for a WinForms application.

The layouts will be designed by myself, and added into the software. The layouts will be used to present the data. Mainly for aesthetics. The application allows the user to enter their information for a CV and they can select a layout for their CV.

Comment: Will the layouts be defined in advance or will they be created on the fly.  What do you mean exactly by layout.  Are you talking about merging of text only?

Comment: Edited question with details of what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I would suggest WPF if you were not committed to a WinForms application.

Instead you can use HTML and swap out the CSS (cascading style sheet) on the fly.  You will need to use a WebBrowser control to host the html (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx).

Otherwise you could creat several controls that could bind to the same data object and swap the controls out.  I like the HTML option better myself.